# Using network link conditioner with Reachability

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I am using reachability from: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability in an objective-c app.  I have it running, startNotifier is called and I see a reachabilityChanged: call when my app starts up.  Now when I use the network link conditioner to simulate different network settings, I was under the assumption that reachabilityChanged: would be called.

Is that not the case or is there another step I need to do in order to simulate different network conditions?  If I turn off the WiFi on my Mac, then I get reachabilityChanged: but not from doing it within network link simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reachability observes the state of the network connection, not the quality of it.

Since you are using network link conditioner you are only affecting the quality of the network like the speed or packet loss.

The only way reachability notifies you about a change is in fact when the network connection is lost or restored, as you have stated in your tests.